# Extending StringConstructor in TypeScript leads to undefined function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript

I am trying to add a static method to the String class in TypeScript 2.5, compiled to ES5.

In StringExtensions.d.ts:

```
declare interface StringConstructor {
    isNullOrEmpty(value: string | null): boolean;
}
```

In StringExtensions.tsx:

```
String.isNullOrEmpty = function(value: string | null) {
    return value == null || value == "";
}
```

When used like this:

```
String.isNullOrEmpty("my string");
```

I get an error in Chrome that "String.isNullOrEmpty" is not a function. However the code compiles just fine using "target": "es5" in tsconfig.json. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had to import the file containing the implementation in the tsx file serving as the main/starting file:

```
import 'Extensions/StringExtensions';
```